# Appbuilder windows client not starting

Tags: telerik, telerik-appbuilder

I am using Telerik Appbuilder windows client. A few days ago a power failure happened. After that the application does not start. When I click on the shortcut in the menu I get a message :verifying application requirements.... after that nothing happens.

The windows client simply does not start.

If anybody can help, I will be thankful

santu ghosh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi everyone I found the solution myself:

I found out the logs folder, and opened the latest log file as per time stamp, and found the name of the use config file, then found the file is empty. I then uninstalled the software, deleted the Data folder under AppData. Then re-installed the software. Then it worked just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You should quit your AppBuilder client and try [this workaround](http://www.telerik.com/forums/debugging-in-simulator-crashing-the-simulator#KoKgVvx9DUu5fD4UJmiUlw).

Comment: Hi Rob
  Without reading that article/knowing this solution, I myself did these steps. I found out the logs folder, and opened the latest log file as per time stamp, and found the name of the use config file, then found the file is empty.
I then uninstalled the software, deleted the Data folder under AppData. Then re-installed the software. Then it worked just fine.

But thanks anyway.